# How do I disable Android permissions checking

Tags: android, permissions

Is there a way to either disable permission checking so an app can run uninhibited, or add all permissions to the APK in a blanket manner?

I have tried adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.*" />` in an attempt to add all members of android.permission, but this is a syntax error, wildcard's are not allowed. I expected it to select everything matching that expression.

Comment: You need to specify permissions or your app won't run.

Comment: Wouldn't allowing apps to disable permission checking completely defeat the purpose of the permission system?

Comment: I wasn't asking for a way to let the APK disable permissions checking. I was asking for either a way to disable it myself, possibly via command line, or whether there was a way for the APK to say "give me everything" as in the example above, in which case the user would have to allow it at install time. This is not for production systems in any case, but would be useful for debugging as it is tedious to have to keep recompiling with new permissions in order debug on systems which have different permissions to the production environment.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to either disable permission checking so an app can run uninhibited

No.

> or add all permissions to the APK in a blanket manner?

Type them all into your manifest. Or build some script that will generate that portion of the manifest for you.

Comment: This is what I currently do. Surprised there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The only feasible solution is to add all available permissions manually. You can find all currently existing permissions [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).